# If column A repeats, sum column 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two columns and if column A repeats I want to sum the values of column B.

A = {1 2 3 3 4 4 4}
B = {1 2 3 4 5 6 7}

the result should look like:

```
A    B
1    1
2    2
3    7
4    18
```

My code:

```
 for i in range(len(a)):
 r= np.sqrt(((x-x[j])**2)+((y-y[j])**2)))
  if r <= A[i] <= r-5:
        B=np.abs((r-0.007)-b[i])
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written so far and any errors you get?

Comment: This is one small part in a larger code. I use a for loop to get the values of B for each A value. I tried summing the values in B outside of the loop, but it only uses the last repeated value. Ex) B = 1, 2, 4, 7

Comment: Then show us what you tried so we could help you to debug your code.

Comment: If the actual code is truly too large to post, a [mcve] would also work.

Comment: I added the basics of the part I need help on

Comment: The code has little to do with your question and is incomplete (many undefined variables)...

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand the question. What are you trying to achieve? When does column A 'repeat'? *edit After looking into it, I get what you're saying. You might want to clear it up a bit for the other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
B1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
A2 = []
B2 = []

for i in range(len(A1)):
    if A1[i] != A1[i + 1]:
        A2.append(A1[i])
        B2.append(B1[i])
    else:
        j = i + 1
        sum = B1[i]
        while j < len(A1) and A1[i] == A1[j]:
            sum += B1[j]
            del A1[j]
            del B1[j]
        A2.append(A1[i])
        B2.append(sum)
        if j >= len(A1):
            break

print A2
print B2
```

output is:

[1, 2, 3, 4]

[1, 2, 7, 18]

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be using the following algorithm:

```
def create_buckets(l):
    return [0]*(max(l)+1)

def fill_buckets(A, B):
    buckets = create_buckets(A)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        buckets[A[i]] += B[i]
    return buckets

A = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
output = fill_buckets(A, B)
for i in range(len(output)):
    if output[i] != 0:
        print(i, output[i])
```

- We make a list with zero's. It's length is equal to the largest value of A+1. (this way, we have every value of A as an index in the list) These are buckets.
- We loop over A. Let's say we get value X on index Y in the loop:

  •  We check the value on list B with the same index (Y)

  •  We add that value to the buckets, on index X (value of A on index Y)
- We print every value of the buckets that is not zero (or you can make another default value if you want to allow zeros).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the  simplest solution.

A1 = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]

B1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
A2 = []

B2 = []

A2.append(A1[0])

B2.append(B1[0])

for i in range(len(A1)-1):

```
if A1[i] != A1[i+1]:
    A2.append(A1[i+1])
    B2.append(B1[i+1])  
else:
    A2.pop()
    A2.append(A1[i+1])
    b = B2.pop()
    B2.append(b+B1[i+1])
```

print A2

print B2

Output:
    A2 = [1,2,3,4]
    B2 = [1,2,7,18]